# SSH config using multiple ProxyJump with keys on remote machines

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to reach any of my server with only one SSH command.
My problem is that when I use "ProxyJump" or "ProxyCommand" the "IdentityFile" is searching for the key on my machine.

**Is there any option in the config to use a remote key for the next jump?**

I have common users starting from the second level of servers, lets call them "secondadmin" and "thirdadmin". Currently I can reach a server in a third level using two ssh commands like this:

```
myuser@first-server: ~/$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa secondadmin@second-server
secondadmin@second-server: ~/$  ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa thirdadmin@third-server
```

I want to emulate this behavior above and don't want to have separate users for everyone on these servers (for now).
I also don't want to copy the private keys of the admins to my or any other user's machine either if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`ProxyJump` works by establishing *TCP tunnel* from your machine towards the target through the proxy. Then it connects to the local tunnel endpoint, reaching the target machine from your computer. The connections towards target (or next proxy) are never originally initiated from those proxies.

Suppose you have the following setup:

```
Host a
   ProxyJump b

Host b
   ProxyJump c

Host c
   ProxyJump d
```

When you run `ssh a`, it does the following, all on the *local machine* (where you run this command):

1. Connect to `d` and make a TCP tunnel, let's say using local port 11111 to `c:22`
2. Connect to `localhost:11111` which leads to c:22, and make a TCP tunnel from local port 22222 to `b:22`
3. Connect to the `localhost:22222` which leads to b:22 and make a TCP tunnel from local port 33333 to `a:22`
4. Connect to `localhost:33333`, ending up in a.

Of course, actual ports will be randomly chosen.

You can observe this by looking into local machine's connection table `ss -npt` after making connection, so you'll see all of them.

Notice that all connections are made from the client machine, so all keys for all intermediate hosts must be available on the local machine. All those machines may not have any keys to connect to each other, because they don't actually establish SSH connections towards each other, only tunnel them.

However, firewalls must allow at least the following: `b` is allowed to `a:22`, `c` is allowed to `b:22`, `d` is allowed to `c:22`, and your computer must be allowed to `d:22`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the keys to the initial server is the only way since the IdentityFile always reads from that server that makes the first connection (also orders the hops). The other servers are just nodes meant to give the proper access origin for the follow up servers.