# ssh multi hop tunnel (two hops) with ssh config and putty (or cygwin)

Tags: ssh-tunnel

### My Environment

I have bastion server, deploy server, production server, redis server
I want to port forward redis server using putty.
local machine -> bastion -> deploy -> production -> redis:6379

#### bastion

`$cat /home/alpha/.ssh/config`

```
Host deploy
    ForwardAgent yes
    Hostname deployment.alpha.co.kr
    User alpha
    Port 9922
    Identityfile ~/.ssh/alpha.pem
```

#### deploy

in deploy, I change user to `beta` and connect do `ssh prod-fe1`

```
sudo -iu beta
ssh prod-fe1
```

below is the ssh config
`$cat /home/beta/.ssh/config`

```
Host prod-fe*
    Hostname %h.prod.server.in
    User charles
    Port 9922
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_charles
```

#### production

in production server, I connect to redis with

`redis://tf-redis-ro.abcde.ng.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379`

### What I want to do

I want to make a tunnel in my local machine(windows, putty)
to connect to the redis!

local machine -> bastion -> deploy -> production -> redis

how can I do this?

if putty is not the right tool for ssh multi hop tunnel with above complex ssh config, could you please recommend me the right tool?

Comment: Why putty? Why cygwin? You can pretty much use *OpenSSH feature* integrated into modern Windows. And then do the configuration in `C:/Users/<profile>/.ssh/config` exactly as on other platforms (for example, as I explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/985777/ssh-config-using-multiple-proxyjump-with-keys-on-remote-machines/1121565#1121565)). The only tricky part is that you can't create this `.ssh` folder with Explorer; use `mkdir` for that.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks a lot! I accomplished the task as exactly what you said!

Comment: and actually I could create `.ssh` folder with explorer :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this! below is my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bastion
  Hostname bastion.server.co.kr
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/alpha.pem
  ForwardAgent yes
  User alpha
  Port 9922

Host deploy
  Hostname deployment.server.co.kr
  User alpha
  Port 9922
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/alpha.pem
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion

Host prod-fe*
  Hostname %h.prod.server.in
  User charles
  Port 9922
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_charles
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p deploy
```

with above config, I used below command to open ssh tunnel

`ssh -L 6379:tf-redis-ro.abcde.ng.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 prod-fe1`

Comment: You can put the tunnel setup into configuration file as well, so your command will shrink down to something like `ssh prod-fe1`. The option is called `LocalForward`. Also you can have several "Host" records for a single actual host, for example, some with tunnel and some without, for different cases.